# How can I solve this 422 error when trying to send information to the database using an axios POST request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, post, axios

I'm facing an interesting error (`POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/signup 422 (Unprocessable Entity)` when making a POST request using `axios` to store user info into my database.

I've created an endpoint using Laravel (PHP framework) and tested via Postman with the right headers and works fine but for some reason, the frontend part of it has me stumped and not sure what to do as I've hit a wall.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I store user info into the DB successfully?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            email: "",
            password: ""
        };
        this.userNameHandler = this.userNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.emailHandler = this.emailHandler.bind(this);
        this.passwordHandler = this.passwordHandler.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    userNameHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value,
        });

        console.log(this.state.username);
    }

    emailHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value,
        });

        console.log(this.state.email);
    }

    passwordHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value,
        });

        console.log(this.state.password);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = {
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        JSON.stringify(user);

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        });

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/signup', user, headers)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("AXIOS ERROR!! " + error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div id="login-row" className="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div id="login-column" className="col-md-6">
                        <div id="login-box" className="col-md-12">
                            <form id="login-form" className="form" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="username" className="text-info">Username:</label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" className="form-control" onChange={this.userNameHandler}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="username" className="text-info">Email:</label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" className="form-control" onChange={this.emailHandler}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="password" className="text-info">Password:</label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" className="form-control" onChange={this.passwordHandler}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-md"
                                           value="Submit"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

Here's my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create user
     *
     * @param  [string] name
     * @param  [string] email
     * @param  [string] password
     * @param  [string] password_confirmation
     * @return [string] message
     */
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
        ]);
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
        ], 201);
    }

    /**
     * Login user and create token
     *
     * @param  [string] email
     * @param  [string] password
     * @param  [boolean] remember_me
     * @return [string] access_token
     * @return [string] token_type
     * @return [string] expires_at
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Logout user (Revoke the token)
     *
     * @return [string] message
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully logged out'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User
     *
     * @return [json] user object
     */
    public function user(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json($request->user());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have not a email field in your form, your have two username field

in this code

```
<div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="username" className="text-info">Username:</label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" className="form-control" onChange={this.userNameHandler}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="username" className="text-info">Email:</label><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" className="form-control" onChange={this.emailHandler}/>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Good catch!  I tried changing it but I still get the same error :(.

Comment: Add the csrf token field in your form, i think this will fixe the error

Comment: hmm, how would I do that in this case?

Comment: The error with code 422 is often a validation error, verify if the name of the fields corresponding to the validation attributes in the controller.

Comment: posted my controller in my original post, I still can't see what's off :(

Comment: I think the issue are here  "name: this.state.name" on the user object, your try to get name in the state instead of username like "name: this.state.username"